# Partition from second hard drive gets mounted as /

Tags: linux, hard-disk

I connected a second hard drive to my computer with the intention of mounting a partition which it contains (an older version of my current Linux partition). What happens after I turn the computer on is that the bootloader from the first drive launches and loads the kernel, also from the first drive, but the partition from the second drive gets mounted as the root filesystem (even though the partition from the first one is visible as `/dev/sda2` and `/etc/fstab` on it says that `/dev/sda2` should be mounted as `/`). Why does it happen and what should I do to get the system to boot as before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is usually caused when you add a drive and forget to change device names in `/etc/fstab` or where ever the root filesystem is referenced.

For example the drive can change its device name from `/dev/sda` to `/dev/sdb`. This is why modern systems use labels or UUIDs to identify filesystems correctly, even if they are reordered for some reason.

Comment: The partition from the first drive is still visible as `/dev/sda2`,, though.

Comment: Don't forget that you can pass device names for the rootfs in the boot manager, too (kernel parameters).

Comment: But the device names for the first drive are still the same!

Comment: Do you have the kernel parameter `root=/dev/sda2` set or is it omitted?

Comment: It's `root=UUID=...`, where the UUID is of the partition on the first drive.

Comment: You haven't told anything about how you installed the new Linux system. Are duplicate UUIDs involved? Are you absolutely sure that the kernel from `/dev/sda` is loading? Are there any hints in the log how devices and partitions are probed and if there are failures/errors?

Comment: I used `dd` to copy the old disk. It didn't occur to me that UUIDs could be duplicated (they are). I guess the cleanest way out of this would be to change the UUIDs on the old disk?

Comment: This should work. However you solve it, be careful not to mix up the old and new drive and their partitions during your next actions. Good luck!